# google tag manager eCommerce

Tags: tags, report, google-tag-manager

I am getting crazy trying to get this to work.
I am pretty new to the whole Google Tag Manager thing, but after reading documentation, I got the basic google analytics to work.

Having said that, I am trying to set up an eCommerce transactions using dataLayer but I cannot seems to get it to work.

I am using the basic example taken on the main site:

```
    var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
        'ecommerce': {
            'purchase': {
                'actionField': {
                    'id': 'T12345',                         
                    'affiliation': 'Online Store',
                    'revenue': '35.43',                     
                    'tax':'4.90',
                    'shipping': '5.99',
                    'coupon': 'SUMMER_SALE'
                },
                'products': [{                          
                    'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',     
                    'id': '12345',
                    'price': '15.25',
                    'brand': 'Google',
                    'category': 'Apparel',
                    'variant': 'Gray',
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'coupon': ''                            
               },
               {
                    'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
                    'id': '67890',
                    'price': '33.75',
                    'brand': 'Google',
                    'category': 'Apparel',
                    'variant': 'Black',
                    'quantity': 1
               }]
            }
       }
   });
```

In my GTM configuration, I have the following:
- Tag Type: Universal Analytics
- Track Type: Page View
- Google Analytics Settings: {{gaTrackingID}}
- Enable overriding settings in this tag: ticked
- Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true
- Use Data Layer

and in the Trigger i have:
 - Trigger Type: Page view
 - Trigger fires on: "Page URL contains /checkout

I forgot to mention that I have two tags enabled, one to log activity on all pages and the second one which should log the purchase.

I can in google Analytics that the visit worked correcty, but the transaction does not.

Also, can someone tell me if the section "CONVERSATIONS -> Ecommerce" displays the standard or Enhanced Ecommerce?

I am a bit confused..

Why the above does not work?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out this morning that the code actually worked, but google analytics takes around 24/48 hours to reflect the changes. this is something I did not read anywhere in most of the documentation I found. This kind of make the whole testing process a bit difficult, as the only thing we can do is to check if the event is fired (as far as I know).

Perhaps there is a better way (and more instant) to test whether an eCommerce data has been pushed to google Analytics?

Comment: You can check the HTTP petitons sent to google analytics. You can do that by directli using the console navigator in the network tab or by using  plugins to make the process easier, for example the one recomended by google ga debgger (chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) when you activate this extension it will log on your console the hits sent to GA (here you have some examples of hits: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#commonhits).

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert page and transaction information into a single 'ecommerce' object and not separated.

Regarding the data displayed in the ecommerce report in Analytics, it depends on whether you have enabled enhanced ecommerce settings or only those standard.